# How to access object attributes shown in a console.log

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `myVar` that I am debugging in Chrome Dev Tools using `console.log(myVar)`. It produces the following result:

[image]

I am able to access `myVar.positions` and `myVar.stack` with no problem. However, when I try to access `myVar.nodeInfo` it returns `undefined`, despite that attribute containing a dict shown in the console. Similarly `myVar.pageBreakCalculated` also returns `undefined` rather than `true`.

Am I either misunderstanding something about what I am seeing in the console, or how to access objects?

Comment: One key thing to learn about the Chrome dev tools is that it logs by reference and thus updates what is printed if the reference changes. In your screenshot, notice this blue icon in the top right with an 'i'? This is Chrome saying that "this value has changed since it was printed". So either the values you want were added after the print of the object, or you printed the sub-properties before they had values for example. Sometimes using JSON.stringify can really help with these timing "issues".

Comment: you can always add `debugger` to your code and it will break on that line, then you can inspect and proceed line by line ...

Comment: Or add break point in google chrome dev tools(in the line in which you are interested). I think this is the best solution because then you can analyze your code line by line

Comment: Thanks, so it would appear that the blue "your data has changed" icon only appears when I expand the tree in Chrome Dev tools. Also it seems that this is when `nodeInfo` is added. What's going on here? It can't be the script itself can it? Is it a Chrome feature?

Comment: I don't think `nodeInfo` is added when you click expand, rather the printed object is updated when you click expand. This means that `nodeInfo` has changed between when you printed it first and when you click expand. Like the other have suggested, you can use the debugger to see when it changes, or print `nodeInfo` directly at multiple places in your code flow, or use JSON.stringify (strings aren't exactly reference types so those won't change once printed)

Comment: What else do you have in your code that might be doing things after you print or perhaps asynchronously?